# "dispute is lost"

Tags: meaning

> He predicts that such factors as the size of the opponents, the
>   potential rate of predation in a habitat, and the probability of
>   winning a **subsequent site if the dispute is lost** will all affect the
>   behavior of spiders in territorial disputes.

I am having problem with bold part. I have two questions:

1. I have two interpretation for "dispute is lost".

First, if they lose the fight (dispute).

Second, If there are no fights (disputes).

which one is the correct one?

2. Does "Subsequent site"  means a place where it comes after dispute?

Comment: Your first interpretation is correct. Note that from the spider's point of view, *winning a [territorial] fight/dispute* is equivalent to winning the ***site*** previously occupied by the beaten opponent. So if the spider knows that most of the other spiders in the local area are bigger and stronger than him, he might fight extra hard when he gets into a dispute with a relatively small opponent - because if he can't beat *this* one, the chance of him beating any *others* (and thus gaining his own territory) is quite low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *dispute* between two spiders can be *won* or *lost* by the challenger.  If it is lost, the challenger must find an alternate (or subsequent) site to live.

However this is only one of the three factors that go into a spider's decision to challenge another spider.  If the spider feels the odds are poor, she might not challenge in the first place.